# Whys the identity $a \times (\nabla \times a) = 1/2\nabla (a^2)-(a\cdot\nabla )a$ holds?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove the identity 
$$a \times (\nabla  \times  a) = 1/2\nabla (a^2)-(a\cdot\nabla)a$$ 
But using the BAC-CAB rule I only get: 
$$a \times (\nabla  \times  a) = \nabla (a^2)-(a\cdot\nabla )a$$ 
I don't know why must be a factor $1/2$ on the right side of the equal sign. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437060/textbfa-times-nabla-times-textbfa-with-index-notation?rq=1 ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942082/prove-frac12-mathbf-nabla-u-cdot-u-u-times-nabla-times-u-u?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much Winther!!!!